# Bootstrap tooltip disappears after second 'show'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I want to produce a manual tooltip based upon some user input. The easiest way was to hide all tooltips and then show the relevent ones.

I've reduced my code down to the bare essentials, and my tooltip keeps disappearing after the second "show".

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.4 and jquery 2.1.3

Is there a problem with doing a show immediatly after a hide or am I missing something in my code?

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox">

<script>
    var toolTipData = {
    placement: 'right',
    title: 'Checkmark checked',
    trigger: "manual"
};
$('#check').tooltip(toolTipData);

$(document).on('change', '#check', function () {
    $('#check').tooltip("hide");
    if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
        $('#check').tooltip("show");
    }
});
</script>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bbrally/4b9g0abh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're experiencing a race condition between when the "hide" event happens and when the "show" event happens. Per the documentation the "hide/show" events actually return to the caller before the "hidden/shown" events fire.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips
Scroll down to the "Methods" section under tooltips
...Returns to the caller **before** the tooltip has **actually been hidden**...

...Returns to the caller **before** the tooltip has **actually been shown**...

I'm not suggesting the code below is a solution (though, it might be good enough?), but an explanation as to what you're running into. Specifically the timeout value of 250ms will slow it down enough such that it works as you're intending.

```
var toolTipData = {
        placement: 'right',
        title: 'Checkmark checked',
        trigger: "manual"
    };
    $('#check').tooltip(toolTipData);

    $(document).on('change', '#check', function () {
        $('#check').tooltip("hide");
        if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#check').tooltip("show");
            }, 250);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't really understand what "returning to the caller" meant and wasn't sure if that was where things were going wrong, but now I know. Perhaps I'll look into rewriting the logic of my code to use if/else's more efficiently.

Comment: Np, Glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('change', '#check', function () {
    if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
        $('#check').tooltip("show");
    }
    else{
        $('#check').tooltip("hide");
    }
});
```

It was trying to hide, even though it shouldn't, separate both cases.

Comment: This does work, but my full program checks many conditions in different parts of my code. "hiding" all and then "showing" the applicable ones seemed less cumbersome that a lot of if/else statements.